# need to get right approach to update data coming to a servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am new to spring and need an approach for my application. I have an application which inserts a user latitude and longitude from android device. According to my new requirement, I need to tag each latitude and longitude to a range given to me. For example: I need to tag my request lat and lat to whether the device user is at home, on road or at customers place.

**I want to know whether a servlet can create different threads for a single request?**

Basically I need to submit the user lat//lng data and at the same time need to tag with the corresponding masters data whether he is at home or office or on road.

I got an alternative that I should run a scheduler in which I will update this data by comparing with the masters data which I got? Is it possible to run separate threads in a servlet request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http servlet request is already handled by a pool of worker threads. If one thread is busy serving one request, the next request is handled by the next available thread.

Based on your requirement I don't see why you need to create a different threads, you can simply use a singleton service class and synchronize the method / critical resources so only one thread at a time can enter it.

To aid on debugging, use `%t` pattern in your log4j (or similar) logging framework to see which thread is serving your request.

Comment: as there are two operations to be done in a single request 1) send response to the user that his location data is submitted 2)at the same time i need to tag that location data to my table containing tags for different Lat/Lng data.I think i need to point out is that i receive request from mobile devices so it is very important to send the response for his request as soon as possible because network os main concern in device-server request-response.I want need a solution by which i can send the response of the request to the device and continue tagging the location data.

Comment: If user does not need to wait for long-running operation to finish (and does not need to know the result immediately), you can create separate thread pool using ExecutorService